# IntelliJ UML plugin show two relations shows two UML relations for the same class dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I recently installed IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 2021.2 and I want to use the built-in UML plugin to generate a class diagram, when I generate the UML diagram using CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + U it shows two UML relations for the same class dependency.
I previously worked with the IntelliJ UML plugin, I think it is version 2020.x and I didn't encounter this problem.

you will find screenshots for my code and the UML diagram that has been generated.

first class :

[image]

second class:

[image]

UML diagram:

[image]

**Should it work like this in this new version of IntelliJ or it's a bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Diagrams | Java Classes | Dependencies | **Show Usages** option.

Comment: it works, I disabled show usages, thank you.